# Using temporary layer as input for other algorithm in Processing script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-3

My script has a single point input layer that will be processed with some logic to extract just some points.

I'd like to pass these extracted points as input of another algorithm (simple buffer) within the same scripts.

I define the final output as `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink`:

```
self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
    self.OUTPUT,
    "Extracted points",
    QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint
    )
)

....

   (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
        parameters,
        self.OUTPUT,
        context,
        source.fields(),
        source.wkbType(),
        source.sourceCrs()
    )
```

running some logic to extract some points:

```
features = source.getFeatures()
for current, feat in enumerate(features):
    if feat.geometry().asPoint() == maximum:
        sink.addFeature(feat, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)
```

then I'm trying to call the buffer algorithm:

```
   buffer = processing.run(
        "native:buffer", {
            'INPUT': sink,
            'DISTANCE': distance,
            'SEGMENTS': 5,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'DISSOLVE': False,
            'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
        }
    )
```

but it does not accept the input:

```
Incorrect parameter value for INPUT
```

Comment: Is the sink layer a QgsVectorLayer object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's two things you need to fix:

- Pass dest_id, not the sink as the parameter value, i.e.

`param = {
            'INPUT': dest_id,
            'DISTANCE': distance,
            'SEGMENTS':5,
            'END_CAP_STYLE':0,
            'JOIN_STYLE':0,
            'MITER_LIMIT':2,
            'DISSOLVE':False,
            'OUTPUT':'memory:'
        }`

- Pass the context and feedback objects to processing.run, so that the child algorithm can access project layers and other objects from the wider context, and can pass feedback messages from the child algorithm (and handle cancelation and progress reports):

`buffer = processing.run("native:buffer", param, context=context, feedback=feedback)`

Comment: thanks for the answer! But even with `dest_id` I have the same error. I don't know if the complete script can help: https://gist.github.com/ghtmtt/54b3253836c3b7aaff910006de091a91

Comment: Try adding a `del sink` line before running the buffer

Comment: Updated with correct answer

Comment: many many thanks @ndawson.. that was exactly what I was missing!